# How to keep between 1 and 2 lines of indentation.

Tags: swift3, indentation, multiple-languages

When reading the book 'Clean Code' by Robert C. Martin, he said that you should always try to keep between 1 and 2 levels of indentation. Three at a max.

Say if we have a dictionary (myDict) which is a type of `[Int:[Int:[Int:String]]]` (swift) and we want to loop through all the values, we would use a piece of code that goes:

```
for (key1, value1) in myDict
{
    for (key2, value2) in value1
    {
         for (key3, value3) in value2
         {
              //Do stuff
         }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the '//Do stuff' part is intented 4 times instead of being <=3.

How would i be able to make this code while staying at a maximum of 3 levels of indentation (preferably 1 or 2)?

Is this posible or not? I eould like the answer to be for all languages, however, if it is not posivle, could it be for Swift?

Comment: You would never keep data in nested dictionaries in the first place!

Comment: What would be the best way of doing that then? I want to save that dicta into NSUserDefaults. All the data is related to each other.

Comment: Show us your data. You have a `String` indexed by 3 integers? I am pretty sure there is some wrapping into objects you can do, e.g. you could wrap the 3 integers into one index object. Please describe what you are doing in detail.

Comment: @Sulthan It contains data for for a certain object in my app. I do not want to post what the data is as it could give away the project that I am working on.

Comment: @iProgram then change the names. I promise you, no one cares what your project is.

Comment: We cannot help you more information without you giving us more details. For example, would you be able to use a dictionary like `[(Int, Int, Int): String]` instead? (Of course, the tuple is not hashable but you could create a struct with 3 ints or use `IndexPath`).

Comment: @Sulthan Think I have figured it out. I now don't need the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First realize that a nested dictionary has no advantage over a flat dictionary if all your data is only inside the deepest dictionary. So let's just merge our indices into one object:

```
struct MyIndex : Hashable {
    let indices: (Int, Int, Int)

    init(_ index1: Int, _ index2: Int, _ index3: Int) {
        self.indices = (index1, index2, index3)
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return indices.2 // this should ideally use all the 3 indices
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: MyIndex, rhs: MyIndex) -> Bool {
        return lhs.indices == rhs.indices
    }
}
```

(by the way, this is exactly what `IndexPath` in UIKit is doing).

Then we can just use our index instead:

```
var dictionary: [MyIndex: String] = [:]

dictionary[MyIndex(0, 0, 0)] = "test"
dictionary[MyIndex(0, 1, 2)] = "test2"

for (index, value) in dictionary {
    print(index.indices, value)
}
```

Instead of 3 nested for cycles, I am iterating the values all at once.

Answer (score 0):

The generic nod not very graceful way is to create functions...

```
func iterateFirstDict(dictionary: [Int: [Int: [Int: String]]]) {
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        iterateSecondDictionary(value)
    }
}

func iterateSecondDictionary(dictionary: [Int: [Int: String]]) {
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        iterateThirdDictionary(value)
    }
}

func iterateThirdDictionary(dictionary: [Int: String]) {
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Obviously you would use function names that are more descriptive but because we cannot see what your data is it's impossible for me to add those here.

A much better way of approaching this would be to have data objects and functions embedded inside them to do the work for you.

Comment: Oops. I accsedently clicked it. I'm on the mobile app.

Comment: @iProgram ah, no worries :-)